# How to construct a good Regex that matches all strings containing query for better performance in ElasticSearch?

Tags: json, regex, elasticsearch

Suppose I create an index in ElasticSearch by simply calling:

```
PUT strings
```

Then I insert documents by calling:

```
POST strings/string/<some_id>
{
    "name": "some_string"
}
```

Now I want to search for all strings that contain the letter 's', for example:

```
GET strings/string
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "name": ".*s.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, this gives me what I want. However, I read from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) that `Matching everything like .* is very slow as well as using look-around regular expressions.`

Question is, how should I construct the regex in order to do the same thing but with a better performance?

Comment: If checking for the match against the string is enough, you could simply use `s` as your regular expression; if `s` match against the string, then, the string contains at least one *s*

Comment: You may use `"name": "[^s]*s.*"`, or `"name": "~(sdf)sdf.*"` (for multicharacter searches).